# Viewing SQL generated by LINQ - Cast exception

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to profile the SQL LINQ is generating when talking to Entity Framework but I am running into an exception.  I found the `ToTraceString()` code on SO but it throws:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Models.DeviceLogEntry]'
>   to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

EF definition:

```
public virtual ICollection<DeviceLogEntry> Errors { get; set; }
```

Code

```
var result = from e in dbDevice.Errors
             where e.Current == true && e.LogEntryType == Models.DeviceLogEntryType.Error
             select e;

var trace = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)result).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: `result` is the _result_ of your query (an Enumerable of Model.DeviceLogEntries) and not an objectquery, so the cast can't happen. At least, that is what the error message seems to say :)

Comment: Do you have visual studio ultimate?

Comment: @oerkelens actually result is a query, because it is not executed

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy : in that case, why does the error message say its's a query result? I assume because the query get's executes when it is referenced? I might be barking up the wrong tree, but if it;s a query, I'd expect the error message to mention it cannot convert a query to an object query, or something like that.

Comment: @oerkelens error does not says it's a query result. It says you have iterator, but it does not say you have started enumerating some data returned from database, or even if query was executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your `result` will be of type `DbQuery<DeviceLogEntry>`, not `ObjectQuery` (`DbQuery<T>` is an adapter over `InternalQuery`, which uses `ObjectQuery`, but both are internal and not available from public API). But if you want to trace generated query, it's very simple - just call [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696144%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) on query:

```
 var trace = result.ToString();
```

`DbQuery<T>` has overridden `ToString()` method, which internally calls `objectQuery.ToTraceString()` and returns string representation of the underlying query.

*UPDATE*: Thus it turns out that `dbDevice` is an instance of `Device` entity, and `Errors` is just a navigation property, then Entity Frameworks works in following way - if lazy-loading is enabled, then during first access of `Errors` property, it loads *all* realted `DeviceLogEntry` entities to `dbDevice` entity. That happens internally, by proxy class which EF generates for lazy-loading. You cannot get SQL which is executed in that case. All queries to `Errors` collection will happen in memory (i.e. it will be Linq to Objects instead of Linq to Entities). So, your `result` will be simple in-memory iterator of already loaded logs.

In order to see generated query, you should create `DbSet` for DeviceLogEntries on your `DbContext` class. Then you should define query:

```
var query =  from e in db.DeviceLogEntries
             where e.Current == true && 
                   e.LogEntryType == Models.DeviceLogEntryType.Error &&
                   e.DeviceId = dbDevice.Id // or use join
             select e;
```

Now `query.ToString()` will show you SQL query generated by Entity Framework.

*NOTE*: If you are using Entity Framework 6, then you also can use [`db.Database.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464) to log executed database queries.

Comment: I was about to say you were amazing but I tried it and get this error `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Models.DeviceLogEntry]` - is there something im missing?

Comment: @Chris have you tried to execute your query? If EF is able to generate SQL, then it should be returned by `ToString()` call. Aslo how full exception looks like?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question with the code im using now.  If I `ToList()` before the `ToString()` I simply get that the type is a List

Comment: @Chris please, don't update question with your new code, because it changes question a lot. Can you provide full exception you have? `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator1[Models.DeviceLogEntry]` is not an exception. It looks like string representation of executed query. `dbDevice` is your `DbContext` class?

Comment: I get no exception using `ToString` as you suggested, the resultant string is what you quoted, rather than the SQL

Comment: @Chris `dbDevice` is your `DbContext` class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44784/discussion-between-sergey-berezovskiy-and-chris)